# Html parameters that passed are not inserting to mysql database

Tags: java

hiii guys, im trapped in a problem from couple of weeks i.e Im currently using netbeans 8.2 and mysql server for database. Problem is in HTML page whatever i pass as arguments in a form  through SERVLETS is not inserting to my table .pls help me out:

```
package arun.kumar;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class liclist extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
           String Name=request.getParameter("nm");
           String Father_name=request.getParameter("fnm");
           String Age=request.getParameter("age");
           String Address=request.getParameter("adr");
           String City=request.getParameter("ct");
           String State=request.getParameter("st");
           String Phone_no=request.getParameter("pn");
           String Vehicle_type=request.getParameter("vh");
           String Vehicle_no=request.getParameter("vn");
           String Fuel=request.getParameter("fl");

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rto","root","linux123"); 
             Statement st = con.createStatement();
                String s=("insert into lic values('"+Name+"','"+Father_name+"','"+Age+"','"+Address+"','"+City+"','"+State+"','"+Phone_no+"','"+Vehicle_type+"','"+Vehicle_no+"','"+Fuel+"'");
       st.executeUpdate(s);
           out.println("register sucess");

          response.sendRedirect("reg.html");


        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";``
    }// </editor-fold>

}




<!doctype html>   
<html>
    <head><title>lreg</title>
    </head>
    <center>REGISTER</center>
<body bgcolor="orange">
    <form action="liclist"  method="post">   
<center>
<br/> <br/>
Name           <input type="text" name="nm" /> <br>
Father's Name  <input type="text"  name="fnm"/><br>
Age            <input type="text"   name="age"/> <br>
Address        <input type="text" name="adr"/> <br>
City           <input type="text" name="ct"/> <br>
State          <input type="text" name="st"/> <br>
Phone no.      <input type="text"  name="pn"/> <br>
type of vehicle<input type="text"  name="vh"/> <br>
Vehicle no     <input type="text" name="vn"/> <br>
Fuel           <input type="text" name="fl"/> <br>

         <input type="submit" value="Register" />
 <input type="reset" />

</form>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are suppressing the `Exception` inside `catch` block `{}`, log the error properly so that you will know the problem

Comment: paste your HTML code too.

Comment: Sorry,Im new to stackoverflow .can u pls temme how to send more code now

Comment: I dont know whats wrong?